# Extend Function in Actionscript 3.0

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, lexer

Hi I am creating a Lexer, Parser, and Interpreter for my own simple scripting language in AS3. I'd like this to work similar to JavaScript in that I want to be able to execute instructions at runtime from a parsed script. There is a library for flash that does this but the issue is that VMFunctions are unable to be treated as native flash functions. I'd like to be able to call addEventListener() on native flash objects from the scripting language but I want to pass VM functions to the listener parameter which accepts only native functions. I might have to put in a work around which I know is possible but it would be more intuitive to have an object that the AVM could recognize as a native function maybe using flash_proxy and the Proxy class. So in short, I'd like to create a custom vm function class that extends the native function class in some way or can be treated as such so that when I pass the custom VM function into the addEventListener() method It will not throw a TypeReference kind of error. Thank you.

Comment: You must try something then ask us for help.and do you really expect us to read all of it?

Comment: You might name the library that you're struggling to implement, so someone could help. Also, `Function` class is final, you can't extend it, so wrap the `addEventListener` into calling a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a short answer: Wrap it. You want to call a `VMFunction` when an event arises? Create an event listener for that event on the control desired, then call the function passing correct data to it. Since this is a parser, it should probably want some text, so here's an example:

```
var tf:TextField; // your text field, populated elsewhere
var parseButton:Sprite; // click this to parse, bla blabla
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    yourVMFunction(tf.text); // parse output if necessary
}
function Parser() { // constructor
    // some code not depicted
    parseButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,onClick);
}
```

The `yourVMFunction` can be a variable of type `Function`, should you need to repopulate the code.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up switching to C++. I know it has been a while since this post but I wanted to give an update. Thanks for the advice. I am currently using function wrappers around function and method pointers in C++ 11 to wrap native functions as you suggested.